# Prevent refresh on Angular2 with ActiveDirectory authentication via adal-ts

Tags: angular, active-directory, adal

I'm using adal-ts to secure an Angular 2 application against an ActiveDirectory. When the user logs in the site is called with some extra parameters once due to the redirect URI passed to adal-ts configuration (mysite.com/#id_token=asdfghjklsdfghjklsdfghjk...). Then it gets refreshed again immediately without any extras and everything works fine.
Why is that so and how can I prevent it?
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't post a comment . Which library you are using ? you need to check how the browser handle the callback function , for example, refer to adal.js :

```
AuthenticationContext.prototype.handleWindowCallback = function (hash) { 
    // This is for regular javascript usage for redirect handling 
    // need to make sure this is for callback 
    if (hash == null) 
        hash = window.location.hash; 
    if (this.isCallback(hash)) { 
        var requestInfo = this.getRequestInfo(hash); 
        this.info('Returned from redirect url'); 
        this.saveTokenFromHash(requestInfo); 
        var token = null, callback = null; 
        if ((requestInfo.requestType === this.REQUEST_TYPE.RENEW_TOKEN) && window.parent && (window.parent !== window)) { 
            // iframe call but same single page 
            this.verbose('Window is in iframe'); 
            callback = window.parent.callBackMappedToRenewStates[requestInfo.stateResponse]; 
            token = requestInfo.parameters[this.CONSTANTS.ACCESS_TOKEN] || requestInfo.parameters[this.CONSTANTS.ID_TOKEN]; 
        } else if (requestInfo.requestType === this.REQUEST_TYPE.LOGIN) { 
            callback = this.callback; 
            token = requestInfo.parameters[this.CONSTANTS.ID_TOKEN]; 
        } 
        try { 
            if (callback) 
                callback(this._getItem(this.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.ERROR_DESCRIPTION), token, this._getItem(this.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.ERROR)); 
        } catch (err) { 
            this.error('Error occurred in user defined callback function', err) 
        } 
        if (!this.popUp) { 
            window.location.hash = ''; 
            if (this.config.navigateToLoginRequestUrl && window.location.href.replace('#', '') !== this._getItem(this.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST)) 
                window.location.href = this._getItem(this.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST); 
        } 
    } 
};
```

window.location.href will redirect to the page and window.location.hash = '' will clear the hash in url .